# MOQ Task Callback Returns Unsupported Expression Context

Tags: c#, moq

I have been wrangling this for hours even pulling in two other collegues and we finally got a syntax the compiler was happy with but then MOQ it appears is now unhappy?!

The code is from a very large project so I'm only going to provide the first level of abstraction otherwise this could very well be the longest post SO has ever seen.

I'll start with my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetPlan_BadPlanID()
{
   ...snip...

   //Create DataAccessTemplate at this point doesn't need anything special
   Mock<IDataAccessTemplate> dataAccessTemplate = new Mock<IDataAccessTemplate>();

   //This is the line that throws the exception   
   dataAccessTemplate
      .Setup(template => template.InvokeAsync<DefaultActionPlan>(context => Task.FromResult(new DefaultActionPlan())))
      .Returns(Task.FromResult(new DefaultActionPlan()));

     ...snip rest of test....
}
```

Now if needed I will show everything being mocked but for brevity I'm going to show just the method in question.

```
public class PlanDataProvider : BaseDomainServiceProvider, IPlanDataProvider
{
    protected IDataAccessTemplate Template { get; set; }


   public async Task<DefaultActionPlan> GetDefaultActionPlan(string referenceListId)
   {
      var objectId = GetObjectId(referenceListId);

      var defaultActionPlan = await Template.InvokeAsync(context => Task.FromResult(EntityStore.GetEntityById<DefaultActionPlan, ObjectId>
      (
         context.ActivityContext as IDataAccessContext,
         typeof(DefaultActionPlan).FullName,
         objectId
       )));

      return RemoveAclData(defaultActionPlan);
   }
}
```

IDataAccess:

```
public interface IDataAccessTemplate : IServiceTemplate
{ //empty for now    }
```

IServiceTemplate:

```
public interface IServiceTemplate
{
   Task<TReply> InvokeAsync<TReply>(Func<ITemplateContext, Task<TReply>> invokeCallback);

   Task<TReply> InvokeAsync<TReply>(Func<ITemplateContext, Task<TReply>> invokeCallback, Action<ITemplateContext, Exception> errorCallback);
}
```

The error:

> System.NotSupportedException was caught HResult=-2146233067
>     Message=Unsupported expression: context => FromResult(new DefaultActionPlan())
>     Source=Moq
>
> StackTrace:
>          at Moq.MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(Expression expression, Boolean isParams)
>          at Moq.MethodCall..ctor(Mock mock, Condition condition, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
>          at Moq.MethodCallReturn..ctor(Mock mock, Condition condition, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
>          at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2..ctor(Mock mock, Condition condition, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
>          at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass1c`2.b__1b()
>          at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
>          at Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition)
>          at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
>          at DataService.Tests.Controllers.ActionPlan.PlanProviderTest.d__3.MoveNext() in c:\Source...\Dev\DataService.Tests\Controllers\Plan\PlanProviderTest.cs:line 52
>     InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this  would change anything but instead of doing this:

```
context => Task.FromResult(new DefaultActionPlan())
```

try this:

```
context => Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<DefaultActionPlan>())
```

and possibly change your returns to this:

```
.ReturnsAsync(new DefaultActionPlan());
```